# embedded C - using "volatile" to assert consistency

Tags: c, embedded, volatile

Consider the following code:

```
// In the interrupt handler file:
volatile uint32_t gSampleIndex = 0; // declared 'extern'
void HandleSomeIrq()
{
    gSampleIndex++;
}

// In some other file
void Process()
{
    uint32_t localSampleIndex = gSampleIndex;   // will this be optimized away?
    PrevSample      = RawSamples[(localSampleIndex + 0) % NUM_RAW_SAMPLE_BUFFERS];
    CurrentSample   = RawSamples[(localSampleIndex + 1) % NUM_RAW_SAMPLE_BUFFERS];
    NextSample      = RawSamples[(localSampleIndex + 2) % NUM_RAW_SAMPLE_BUFFERS];
}
```

My intention is that `PrevSample`, `CurrentSample` and `NextSample` are consistent, even if `gSampleIndex` is updated during the call to `Process()`.

Will the assignment to the `localSampleIndex` do the trick, or is there any chance it will be optimized away even though `gSampleIndex` is volatile?

Comment: It won't be optimized away exactly because of `volatile` (actually what `volatile` prevents is value caching, code to be removed and moved, in respect to other `volatile` variables, see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you access `volatile` variable just once (and it's the only `volatile` one in that function) so you don't need to worry about [code reorganization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html) that compiler may do (and `volatile` prevents). What standard says for these optimizations at §5.1.2.3 is:

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).

Note last sentence: *"...no needed side effects are produced (...accessing a volatile object)"*.

Simply `volatile` will prevent any optimization compiler may do around that code. Just to mention few: no instruction reordering respect other `volatile` variables. no expression removing, no caching, no value propagation across functions.

BTW I doubt any compiler may break your code (with or without `volatile`). Maybe local stack variable will be elided but value will be stored in a registry (for sure it won't repeatedly access a memory location). What you need `volatile` for is value visibility.

**EDIT**

I think some clarification is needed.

Let me safely assume you know what you're doing (you're working with interrupt handlers so this shouldn't be your first C program): CPU word matches your variable type and memory is properly aligned.

Let me also assume your interrupt is not reentrant (some *magic* `cli`/`sti` stuff or whatever your CPU uses for this) unless you're planning some hard-time debugging and tuning.

If these assumptions are satisfied then **you don't need atomic** operations. Why? Because `localSampleIndex = gSampleIndex` is atomic (because it's properly aligned, word size matches and it's `volatile`), with `++gSampleIndex` there isn't any race condition (`HandleSomeIrq` won't be called again while it's still in execution). More than useless **they're wrong**.

One may think: *"OK, I may not need atomic but why I can't use them? Even if such assumption are satisfied this is an *extra* and it'll achieve same goal"* . **No, it doesn't**. Atomic has not same semantic of `volatile` variables (and seldom `volatile` is/should be used outside memory mapped I/O and signal handling). Volatile (usually) is useless with atomic (unless a specific architecture says it is) but it has a great difference: *visibility*. When you update `gSampleIndex` in `HandleSomeIrq` standard guarantees that value will be immediately visible to all threads (and devices). with atomic_uint standard guarantees it'll be visible in a *reasonable amount of time*.

To make it short and clear: **volatile and atomic are not the same thing**. Atomic operations are useful for concurrency, volatile are useful for lower level stuff (interrupts, devices). If you're still thinking *"hey they do *exactly* what I need"* please read few useful links picked from comments: [cache coherency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93069) and a [nice reading](http://lwn.net/Articles/586854/) about atomics.

**To summarize:**
In your case you may use an atomic variable with a lock (to have both atomic access and value visibility) but no one on this earth would put a lock inside an interrupt handler (unless absolutely definitely doubtless unquestionably needed, and from code you posted it's not your case).

Comment: I think your answer lacks a conclusion — you're saying `volatile` is not good enough, right?

Comment: @jch no, **I'm not saying that** especially because volatile is pretty enough in his scenario (of course assuming his target is 32 bit and gSampleIndex is properly aligned, IMO a pretty safe assumption otherwise he would worry about alignment instead of compiler optimizations about volatile). If we can assume this then we don't have to worry about atomic operations because uint32_t is right size, right aligned and IRQ are rightly disabled during HandleSomeIrq - reentrant code in IRQ handler? No, thank you.

Comment: The qualifications expressed in your last sentence are necessary.  Please add them to your answer.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.  You're confused because of the different definitions of `volatile` in C and C#.

Comment: @jch and where on earth C specs says you can replace _volatile_ with _atomic_ because actually _atomic_ has something _more_ (instead of something different)? Are you ranting that changes in "atomic_" variables will immediately propagate across all threads (and this is by standard)? Where on specs? If you quote specs (instead of...well nothing) I'll be free to _double_ upvote your answer. Also just explain what you think volatile does compared to atomic (in general and in this case) would be helpful to understand...

Comment: Let me expand little bit more: volatile usage in C is pretty limited (and often what we need is atomic, for concurrency) but they're different, they have different purposes and this is not that case. Volatile in C is more similar to what it means on Java than in C# and no, what is done by volatile cannot be done by atomic unless something else is also used (lock? anyway a barrier). Nothing to do with this in C#, sorry. Yes you _may_ lock and atomic instead of volatile to have a similar behavior but..._who_ would do it in a interrupt handler? What's for?

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but I think you took a pretty straightforward answer of yours (concerning volatile, which was the question), and then went "off the reservation" when you started talking about atomics.  There are atomic accesses from the hardware perspective, the new C11 concept of atomics, etc. Then when you refer to "atomics" or "atomic", it's not clear what you're referencing.  Said another way, I think your "EDIT" actually confused things ("To make it short and clear: volatile and atomic are not the same thing") - OP never said anything about atomics, correct?

Comment: @Dan you're absolutely right. I added "edit" to answer other comments (jch) than to answer OP. From OP perspective first part should be enough and I'm not (trying!) to discuss about atomic access. I always wrote "atomic" meaning C11 "atomic_" variables. What I was trying to do (failing, I see) is to explain why you can't _replace_ "volatile" with "atomic_" and live happy, thinking it's done. Moreover I would make clear the price you pay (also, but not only, in performance) to use "atomic_" (presumably without knowing what it'll do). Well I know I haven't the _touch_ to explain things :(

Answer (score 8):

In principle, `volatile` is not enough to guarantee that `Process` only sees consistent values of `gSampleIndex`.  In practice, however, you should not run into any issues if `uinit32_t` is directly supported by the hardware.  The proper solution would be to use atomic accesses.

## The problem

Suppose that you are running on a 16-bit architecture, so that the instruction

```
localSampleIndex = gSampleIndex;
```

gets compiled into two instructions (loading the upper half, loading the lower half).  Then the interrupt might be called between the two instructions, and you'll get half of the old value combined with half of the new value.

## The solution

The solution is to access `gSampleCounter` using atomic operations only.  I know of three ways of doing that.

### C11 atomics

In C11 (supported since GCC 4.9), you declare your variable as atomic:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

atomic_uint gSampleIndex;
```

You then take care to only ever access the variable using the documented atomic interfaces.  In the IRQ handler:

```
atomic_fetch_add(&gSampleIndex, 1);
```

and in the `Process` function:

```
localSampleIndex = atomic_load(gSampleIndex);
```

Do not bother with the `_explicit` variants of the atomic functions unless you're trying to get your program to scale across large numbers of cores.

### GCC atomics

Even if your compiler does not support C11 yet, it probably has some support for atomic operations.  For example, in GCC you can say:

```
volatile int gSampleIndex;
...
__atomic_add_fetch(&gSampleIndex, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
...
__atomic_load(&gSampleIndex, &localSampleIndex, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
```

As above, do not bother with weak consistency unless you're trying to achieve good scaling behaviour.

### Implementing atomic operations yourself

Since you're not trying to protect against concurrent access from multiple cores, just race conditions with an interrupt handler, it is possible to implement a consistency protocol using standard C primitives only.  [Dekker's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) is the oldest known such protocol.

Comment: @bavaza IMO just wrong. Atomic and volatile are different things, volatile guarantees value will be _visible_ to other threads immediately. Atomic (without any other _tool_ around them) just guarantees that _access_ is...atomic (even if memory is unaligned and CPU word doesn't match variable size). They don't guarantees value will be _visible_ to the other threads immediately. Atomic doesn't. It's just ANOTHER thing.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti - you are correct, although I do find the answer helpful.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti there is no such guarantee with `volatile`.  On a multiprocessor architecture, a write of a `volatile` value can be delayed forever.  Atomic with sequential consistency (which is what I recommend in my answer) guarantees that the value becomes visible to the other threads.

Comment: @jch of course it's guaranteed (otherwise there is no reason at all to have `volatile`). On **every** microprocessor architecture a write of a `volatile` **MUST** be (if compiler follows _any_ standard) written immediately (compiler will generate `mov` or whatever `store` instruction is on target CPU). Always. Absolutely. On most (all? I doubt about Itanium) architecture cache coherency between CPUs is managed by hardware itself (otherwise can you imagine the pain?) and in any case nothing `atomic_` may change (if it's not then memory barrier is required and it's not implied with `atomic_`).

Comment: Of course for each `mov mem, reg` or `store` there will always be the counterpart `mov reg, mem` or `load`. The point is that `atomic_` doesn't replace `volatile` exactly as `volatile` can't replace `atomic_` because they do different things.

Comment: I think you're confusing `volatile` in C# with `volatile` in C.  Please check the C (not C#) spec and come back.

Comment: :/ no jch, I'm not confusing C with C#...take a look to **C** spec and feel free to post where they say that atomic_ has same _visibility_ than volatile (BTW also in C++ with std::atomic it's the same) and...well I don't even understand what **you** think volatile is for!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti @jch jch looks right to me. `volatile` only forces the _compiler_ to emit the appropriate `mov` or `lock mov` insn, and in the right order. But that's separate from the memory model and cache coherence! If one processor writes a line and the second reads it, the x86 memory model (for one) _doesn't_ enforce the second to see what the first wrote at once, because stores can be buffered on cache misses and invalidations can be queued. For that reason we have architectural `sfence`, `lfence` and `mfence` instructions to flush out store buffers and drain invalidate queues.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist cache coherency even on multicore and also multiprocessor systems **is guaranteed** on X86 (well also on X64). What's not guaranteed is update order (see also [this post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93069)). I'm not sure about Itanium architecture.

Comment: That said atomic operations _may_ (or not!) be implemented with lock (according to memory alignment and word size), what's required is to respect _their_ memory model (and default one is pretty strict). Where the problem is? User code is inside an interrupt handler!!! Something that should be d*** fast (even volatile, of course, has a price to pay but it's lower). If OP's architecture has cache coherency (as it's pretty common on multiprocessor/multicore systems) then (as I said in my answer) volatile will give _visibility_ without locks (who want locks or mfence on interrupt handler?).

Comment: In OP code, I guess but it's not strictly required by C standard, that assignment (even without volatile) won't be removed (and if elided then value will be parked in register) BUT changes won't be immediately visible (or they won't be visible at all). That's what volatile is for. It's the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Unless you (who writes code with atomic_) has a **deep** knowledge and control around them you seldom need them on _very_ low level stuff because they're _high level_ enough to be used in _every day programming_. You may end up to pay a very high price to use a _fancy_ feature you may not need (in this context). Nice reading: http://lwn.net/Articles/586854/

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti jch and I are not disputing that _cache coherency_ is guaranteed and in hardware. What I and jch are pointing out is that cache coherency _itself_ does not supply the guarantees you believe it does on x86; In particular, because the writing thread did not flush its store buffer with a store-fence (just after the synchronizing store) and because the reading thread did not drain its invalidation queue with a load-fence (just before the synchronizing load), the x86 memory model allows for a stale value to be loaded. See here: http://www.sti.uniurb.it/aldini/mvss/2014s3.pdf.

Comment: If cache coherency is guaranteed in hardware then it'll do **exactly** what OP needs. In paper you linked problem is clearly exposed but when hardware supports c.c. it simply doesn't exist (assuming _compiler_ won't optimize memory access away). If c.c. is supported then (from sw PoV) cache doesn't exist (ignoring performance issues and cache-friendly coding, of course). When you write to memory then value is _instantly_ visible to all cores/CPUs. Comments are not proper place for a long discussion and question itself may need more details but:

Comment: c.c. will propagate changes (it's exactly what it is for!!!) and volatile will disable compiler optimizations (reordering, register usage, value propagation and others). Issue we still have is **reording made by CPU** itself. It's something completely different and atomic_ will not help you here unless you carefully design your interrupt handler routine. BUT (sorry if I must stress about this) it's an interrupt handler, d*** short and fast, for sure not the point where you put code _out of your strict control_. Volatile (even if originally designed for memory mapped I/O) here works pretty well

Comment: because it prevents optimizations and it propagate values (if hw has support for that). Problem of instruction reordering at CPU level can be addressed just with a careful code design (as an interrupt handler must be) and, anyway, if you code without thinking about it even atomic_ won't help you (or you'll introduce subtle bugs you think you're protected against). You may even introduce a m.b. after each write, why we don't do it? Performance, of course. atomic_ is good at high level, volatile (with hw supports) is good at low level where threading issues must be considered more carefully.

Comment: Last from my first comment of this sequence: _"cache doesn't exist"_. Think about poorly designed sw that need to **set** core/CPU affinity (not because of performance but because of correctness). To summarize: can I use "atomic_" here and does it solve OP problem? Yes (assuming some other relaxations on his requirements about timing). Is it right choice? No, it's wrong because it's not something for such low level stuff, it's overkill, it blast performance (where you shouldn't) and, if you know what you're doing, it's even harder to tune.

Comment: FAQ style: Q) then should I use volatile everywhere? A) No, absolutely not. Only if you have hardware support, (IMO) if you have one writer and multiple readers and in very small specific highly optimized code points. It's especially true for flags and counters (without other logic around and where reordering isn't an issue but performance are). Q) Should I use atomic_ everywhere? In higher level code absolutely yes but don't have the wrong sense of security your code is thread safe. They're half-way between volatile and higher level synchronization structures (such us critical semaphores).

Comment: In that small routine if you need more than volatile (I see that counter like a _jiffie_) then probably you need to directly jump to _true_ critical sections (give all said in previous comments here volatile can be seen as a - pardon me - _small and simple_ critical section). Anything else is just something that gives you a false sense of security (with the excitement to use a new fancy feature, BTW unknown and not understood by most of us) paying very high price in performance (and possibly debugging time in future).